# Ultralight - how to minimize window

Tags: c++, windows, titlebar, awesomium

I am making my first app with Ultralight and I am trying to make a custom title bar. The problem is: I am not able to minimize my window. Currently, I tried using the ShowWindow function and the GetForegroundWindow to grab y window but, it just minimize the window and the one beside it. If anyone have any question or clarification needed feel free to ask them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in Ultralight's github repository, ultralight is currently not supporting borderless windows

> AppCore is currently under active development and only supports single-window apps at this writing. A number of planned features (app icons, automatic packager, borderless windows with custom draggable titlebars, etc) are missing but on the way.

Comment: Thx for your answer!